# Taking a Python course and learning about bisection search, confused on why my semantics are incorrect

Tags: python

Our assignment is to write a code that will guess a secret number from 0 to 100.
This is my piece of code:

```
low = 0
mid = 50
high = 100
secretnum = "Is your secret number " + str(mid) + "?"
print"Please think of a number between 0 and 100!"
print secretnum
herp = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")
while herp != 'c':
    if herp == 'h':
        high = mid
        mid = int((mid + low)/2)
    elif herp == 'l':
        low = mid
        mid = int((mid + high)/2)
    else:
        print"Sorry, I did not understand your input."
    print secretnum
    herp = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")
if herp == 'c':
    print "Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(mid)
```

This is the output:

```
Is your secret number 50?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. h
Is your secret number 50?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. l
Is your secret number 50?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. c
Game over. Your secret number was: 37
```

Comment: Note that `secretnum` is evaluated once only, so when `mid` is changed it is not updated.

Comment: I realized the int + str error, but what I need help with is that my output keeps on spitting out "Is your secret number 50?" Why does it do this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Raufio pointed out, Python strings are immutable. To get around the problem with 50 being repeated over and over, you need to call str(mid) again when you print out the question. For example:

```
low = 0
mid = 50
high = 100
secretnum = "Is your secret number: " 
print"Please think of a number between 0 and 100!"
print secretnum + str(mid) + "?"
herp = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")
while herp != 'c':
    if herp == 'h':
        high = mid
        mid = int((mid + low)/2)
    elif herp == 'l':
        low = mid
        mid = int((mid + high)/2)
    else:
        print"Sorry, I did not understand your input."
    print secretnum + str(mid) + "?"
    herp = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")
if herp == 'c':
    print "Game over. Your secret number was:", mid
```

Comment: You are my savior, sir. (/mam. Whatever applies.) On another note, If you did 'l' and then 'c', my code guessed it perfectly. So, herp derp, I bid thee adieu.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I tried it again and it turned out that I was being an idiot hence my later edit to remove the comment. Please feel free to accept this or whichever other answer was most helpful. :)

Comment: Oh no, this was by far the best answer. Mostly because you gave me the answer, which rocked and saved me lots of time, because, knowing me, it would take me quite near forever to figure out what to actually do. So, thank you. :3

Answer (score 2):

for the error change it to:

```
print "Game over. Your secret number was:",mid
```

For the outputting 50 over and over, change `print secretnum` in the while to:

```
print "Is your secret number " + str(mid) + "?"
```

when you set `secretnum="Is your secret number " + str(mid) + "?"` at the beginning, it creates a string, a string completely separate from mid. So if you change mid, the change wont be seen in the string.

Python strings are **immutable** meaning that once they are made, they are done. You can't change the content of a string, without completely remaking it. What `str(mid)` does is create a string representation of `mid`. In this case the string `"50"` is created and put into the string, never to be modified. So when you are displaying a string you need to make sure it is displaying the most recent value by calling `str(mid)` again.

Comment: So how can I make it so mid becomes mutable? Or can I not? VERY confused.

Comment: `mid` is an `int`, and ints are mutable. It's just that what is returned by `str(mid)` is not, and if you change `mid` you need to call `str(mid)` again to get _another_ string to display.

Answer (score 1):

in the last line you simply put:

`print "Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(mid)`

This is because python wants to make sure you really know what you're doing -- that is adding two strings together, not an int and a string -- which is forbidden. The str() function simply changes anything you give it to a string. With regards to your semantics problems, I think this version of the code has got expected behaviour:

```
low = 0  
mid = 50  
high = 100  
print "Please think of a number between 0 and 100!"  
herp = 50  
while herp != 'c':  
    print "Is your secret number " + str(mid) + "?"
    herp = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is to low. Enter 'c' to indicate the guess is correct")   
    if herp == 'h':  
        high = mid  
        mid = int((mid + low)/2)  
    elif herp == 'l':  
        low = mid  
        mid = int((mid + high)/2)  
    else:  
        print"Sorry, I did not understand your input."  
if herp == 'c':  
    print "Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(mid)
```

Comment: Please test the code the OP posts when they're nice enough to provide a reproducible example like this. The real problem was a flaw in the logic that only Raufio has addressed so far, you would have noticed it pretty quickly if you'd tried out the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 20

`print "Game over. Your secret number was: " + mid`

to

`print "Game over. Your secret number was: ", mid`

or

`print "Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(mid)`

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that! But another thing is that if I type "h" or "l" as my raw_input, it'll spit "Is your secret number 50?" over and over. That's the problem in my semantics.

Answer (score 0):

At the very last line, you typed `print "Game over. Your secret number was: " + mid`.
However, `mid` is a number, and adding it to a string doesn't make any sense. You need to convert it to a string first.

There are several ways to do this. You could change it to:

- `print "Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(mid)`
  ...to turn `mid` into a string
- `print "Game over. Your secret number was: ", mid`
  ...so that Python will treat the string and `mid` as two variables, and automatically add a space between them

.

```
low = 0
mid = 50
high = 100
secretnum = "Is your secret number " + str(mid) + "?"
print"Please think of a number between 0 and 100!"
print secretnum
herp = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")
while herp != 'c':
    if herp == 'h':
        high = mid
        mid = int((mid + low)/2)
    elif herp == 'l':
        low = mid
        mid = int((mid + high)/2)
    else:
        print"Sorry, I did not understand your input."
    print secretnum
    herp = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")
if herp == 'c':
    print "Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(mid)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was building my code I had the same problem at first. 
After looking over your code I've noticed few errors and I'll highlight them here:

1. You did not used raw_input to ask the user for the number
2. You shouldn't use the 'c' parameter for your while
3. Your while should come after the raw_input question

   num = raw_input("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")

   ```
   while mid != num:
       print ( "Is your secret number " + str(mid) + "?")
       herp = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")
   ```

See this here, you use the while so it runs until the mid is different than the number that the user chose, it's very important to have that print therem otherwise you wont be able to see the new guess of the program after you chose if the first guess was too low or too high.

1. There is no need to repeat the piece "mid = int(low + high)/2" over and over, just use it after your else and each time the while loop runs it will change the value of mid.
2. you need to start the if/elif/else code with the letter 'c'
3. You can delete the "print secretnum" line and the one after that

   if herp == 'c':

   ```
           break
       elif herp == 'l':
           low = mid

       elif herp == 'h':
           high = mid

       else:
           print"Sorry, I did not understand your input."
       mid = int(low + high)/2
   print "Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(mid)
   ```

   Notice that I used the "break" to leave the while loop and so the message Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(mid) is printed.

The final result should look like this:

```
low = 0
high = 100
mid = (high + low)/2

num = raw_input("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")

while mid != num:
    print ( "Is your secret number " + str(mid) + "?")
    herp = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")

    if herp == 'c':
        break
    elif herp == 'l':
        low = mid
        #mid = int(mid + high)/2
    elif herp == 'h':
        high = mid
        #mid = int(mid + low)/2
    else:
        print"Sorry, I did not understand your input."
    mid = int(low + high)/2
print "Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(mid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code...

```
max_num=100
min_num=0
guess = int(abs(max_num/2))
print("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")
for i in range(min_num,max_num):
  text = "Is your secret number "+str(guess)+"?\nEnter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. "
  xx = raw_input(text)
  if(xx == 'h'):
    max_num = guess
    guess = int((guess + min_num)/2)
  elif(xx == 'l'):
    min_num = guess
    guess = int((guess + max_num)/2)
  elif(xx == 'c'):
    print("Game over. Your secret number was:"+str(guess))
  else:  
    print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
    xx = str(input(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to include `int((mid + low)/2)`under every `if-elif` block. Here's the approved code for the same exercise:

```
print("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")
low = 0
high = 100
guess = (low + high) // 2

while True:
    print("Is your secret number " + str(guess) + "?")
    suggest = input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")
    if suggest == 'l':
        low = guess
    elif suggest == 'h':
        high = guess
    elif suggest == 'c':
        print("Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(guess))
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
    guess = (low + high) // 2
```